# Using window.open to open a UNC path in chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, window.open

I have a unc path like this:
`\\fs7600\datadirectory`

I'm trying to open it from my jQUery via window.open if the user clicks a button.  If I enter this in to the address bar in chrome directly, it works great.  But it doesn't work with window.open- that just shows a blank page.

Works with IE just fine...

Anyone have any trick to get this to work from jQuery/javascript WITHOUT a chrome extension?

Comment: Browser security...You need the extension

Comment: Yep I know it's for security reasons.  But what sux is that while IE may be more 'insecure', it's what our users will be using because they can have this functionality.  For an intranet, that chrome blocks this is lame.